# Dynamically reconfiguring map_start_x/y

Tags: slam, navigation, lidar, mapping, hector-mapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My quick question is: can we change the map_start_x and map_start_y parameters of the hector_mapping node once it's running? Or do we need to restart the node with those parameters?

Thank you in advance,

Ernest

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/54994/dynamically-reconfiguring-map_start_x/y/) by [Ernest](https://answers.ros.org/users/4002/ernest/) on ROS Answers with karma: 341 on 2013-02-11

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Those parameters are standard ROS parameters not using [dynamic_reconfigure](http://ros.org/wiki/dynamic_reconfigure), so they cannot be changed during runtime.

You can play around with the undocumented "initialpose" topic however. This will set the location of the robot to the specified pose and go on with SLAM from there, inspired by how it's done in [AMCL](http://www.ros.org/wiki/amcl).

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2013-02-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1